# What is the 'office of call-boy'?

Tags: meaning, context

From the short story [*Percival Bland's Proxy*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks14/1402941h.html),
by Austin Freeman written in 1913;

> And thus was the curtain rung down on the first act. The second act opened only a couple of days later, **the office of call-boy**—**to pursue the metaphor to the bitter end**—being discharged by a Belgian police official who emerged from the main entrance to the Bank of England. What should have led Percival Bland into so unsafe a neighbourhood it is difficult to imagine, unless it was that strange fascination that seems so frequently to lure the criminal to places associated with his crime. But there he was within a dozen paces of the entrance when the officer came forth, and mutual recognition was instant. Almost equally instantaneous was the self-possessed Percival's decision to cross the road.

Percival Bland is a criminal, making counterfeit money and being chased by police.

From the above text

1. What does 'office of call-boy' mean?
2. What is 'to pursue the metaphor to the bitter end'?

I can't simply figure those phrases out; hoping somebody will explain them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1)** What does '*the office of call-boy*' mean?

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/call-boy) *call-boy* is:

> A person in a theatre who summons actors when they are due on stage.

The [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/office?q=office) defines *office* as:

> an important position of authority, especially in government; the work and duties connected with this

The author reemphasises the authoritarian position of the *call-boy* with the term "*the office*", even though the term *call-boy* can be comprehended as someone who has authority.

---

**Q2)** What is '*to pursue the metaphor to the bitter end*'?

The phrase '*... the bitter end*' from the quote gives it away. This phrase is defined by the [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bitter-end) as:

> the conclusion of a difficult or unpleasant situation; the last or furthest extremity

Defining a metaphor from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/metaphor?s=t):

> a figure of speech in which a term or phrase is applied to something to which it is not literally applicable in order to suggest a resemblance

The author adds:

> ... a Belgian police official who emerged from the main entrance to the Bank of England.

The metaphor is the shift or transfer of authority from the *call-boy* to the *Belgian police official*, as there is no literal *transfer* or *shift*.

---

**Q1 & Q2:**
The call-boy who has control of who does what and where they are on the stage. Alternatively the call-boy has an authoritarian figure, but now, the tables have turned, and there is a Belgian police officer in the main entrance to the Bank of England. Now the authoritarian figure has shifted from him to the Belgian police officer. The metaphor is the transition, shift or transfer of the *call-boys* authority to the Belgian Police official. It's usually the *call-boy* who summons individuals when they are due on stage, but alas *a Belgian police official* emerges from the main entrance, making it a very *unpleasant situation*. As the consequences will be very unpleasant, the author states "*to the bitter end*".

Comment: Of note:  In sailing lingo "bitter end" refers to the loose end of a rope (such as the "sheet" used to control a sail).  If the bitter end slides out of your grip then you've lost control of the rope, the sail, and possibly the boat.

Comment: A good answer, but not 100% correct: _office_ here means _role_. At [this link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/office?q=office) it is listed as sense 6, "important position". Of course call-boy is not an important position, but the author is here using high-flown language for comic effect.

Answer (score 4):

The author is using an extended theater metaphor, and calling attention to his use of said metaphor. Curtain, first act, second act, call boy are all terms from theater. The call-boy is a person in a theater who summons actors when they are due on stage. Office is used in the sense of position or role. So: The role of call-boy (for me to continue the theater metaphor to the bitter end) being discharged by a Belgian police officer...

Answer (score 0):

> And thus was the curtain rung down on the first act.

The author uses a stage/theatre metaphor to explain that the first part of the story has come to an end.

> The second act opened only a couple of days later,

He continues the use of the state/theatre metaphor to explain that the story he is telling continues…

> the office of call-boy — *to pursue the metaphor to the bitter end*

This is an aside, from the author to the reader, to explain that the next part of the story involves a pivotal character who sets the next part in motion, or draws us back to the events in motion. The phrase "to the bitter end" means, "to take it to the extreme". The author is acknowledging that presenting the story as a "first act", "second act" etc. is a metaphor and that further introducing the "call-boy" (a person who calls people back to the show at the end of an intermission) is to belabour or over-use the stage/theatre metaphor.

> being discharged by a Belgian police official who emerged from the main entrance to the Bank of England.

In other words: the first part of the story has transpired, and seemingly come to a close. That is, until a character (the Belgian police official) does something in order to herald further events.

The role of the 'call-boy' is fulfilled by a Belgian police official.

I hope that helps to explain the passage! :)

Answer (score 0):

Q1: What does 'office of call-boy' mean?
A: Here, "office" means role or job, and the job was discharged, or performed, by the Belgian police official.  A call-boy is a "person in a theater who summons actors when they are due on stage." (See http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/call-boy )  This might be similar to the role of production assistant today.

Q2: What is 'to pursue the metaphor to the bitter end'?
A: In writing or speaking, to pursue a metaphor means to continue to use imagery consistent with the analogy implied by the metaphor.  The metaphor here is the comparison of the action of the story, with the action in a theater during the performance of a play, with a first act, a second act and the curtain in between.  To pursue something to its end is to finish it.  The bitter end is the final definite end of something, as the very end of a rope.   So to pursue something to its bitter end is to finish it completely, to exhaust it. "Bitter" here connotes unpleasantness, but denotes finality or extremity. The narrator's comparison of the policeman to a theatrical call-boy is the last and final part of this metaphor.  By using the phrase "the bitter end" the narrator wryly suggests that his own metaphor (of a play in a theater) is somewhat tired, tiresome, played out, exhausted or overworked.  It does not mean that the characters themselves are pursuing anything bitter or unpleasant.